# What is the correct way to nest Schema.org Property Types inside an Object Type in JSON-LD

Tags: json, schema.org

**Question:**

How to nest a [Schema.org](https://Schema.org) `property` types inside an `Object Type` in a `JSON-LD` code?

**Context:**

I have a website with pages about the biography of persons. I have a validated `JSON-LD` code for the [Schema.org Person](https://Schema.org/Person) Object Type.

I want to expand the code to include the persons that came before and after a person in a certain role. For example, if the page is about a mayor of a city, I want to add the previous and following mayors.

The closest properties I could find are `follows` for the previous mayor ([link](https://schema.org/follows)) and `followee` ([link](https://schema.org/followee)) for the following mayor.

**The Problem:**

The property `follows` was validated with no problems, but `followee` gave an error if placed directly under the `Person` type as it requires a `FollowAction` type.

`The property @followee is not recognized by Google for an object of type Person.`

**Workaround Tried:**

I tried to nest the code, but I could not do this successfully.
For example:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "john Citizen",
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org/",
          "@type": "FollowAction",
           "followee": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Steve"
            }   
        }
   }
</script>
```

I tired several other variations, but all led to errors. Are there any feasible correction to the code, or alternative ways to achieve the goal?

Comment: I think follows and the FollowAction followee are about social interactions like say on Twitter. Not for what you are trying to do. There's no direct way to link from Person to a FollowAction (potentialAction could be used bot also makes no sense), so you would need to define FollowAction separately and have it reference the persion as the agent.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, I don't think follows or FollowAction are appropriate for your use.

For academic purposes, there is a way to mark up FollowAction inside a person. As FollowAction can reference a Person via it's agent, but not the other way around, you can use the reverse property to indicate a kind of backward reference:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "john Citizen",
    "@reverse": {
     "agent":
          {
            "@type": "FollowAction",
             "followee": {
              "@type": "Person",
              "name": "Steve"
              }   
          }
        }
   }
</script>
```